# Per-link DNS settings with systemd-resolved

Tags: dns, openvpn, systemd

It doesn't make much sense to me why per-link DNS settings would be useful. Wouldn't any DNS server you want to use have to be part of a global list before you can decide which interface to send the traffic through? That notion seems like it is supported in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/423882/configure-a-dns-server-per-nic-interface-eth0-eth1).

I am trying to use `update-systemd-resolved` in my `openvpn` configuration file, and I see that it is setting the DNS only on the tunnel interface, using `resolvectl status`. `nslookup` fails and shows that it is only using DNS servers in the `Global` list outputted by `resolvectl status`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; each interface can additionally have a list of **domain suffixes** for which it is the primary one. For example, a tunnel interface for a corporate VPN can be assigned `corp.example.com` or some other domain that is only possible to resolve through the VPN – without needing to send all *other* DNS queries through the VPN. (This avoids hurting latency and/or compromising privacy.)

This server selection based on domain is implemented *inside* systemd-resolved, and in order for it to work properly, your resolv.conf must point only to 127.0.0.53 (which is systemd-resolved's DNS proxy listener) and no other nameserver.

But if you let Nslookup bypass systemd-resolved and just put the actual DNS servers in resolv.conf (which has no way of expressing such configuration), then there will indeed be just a single global list.

Overall, this is very much like the per-domain "server" option in dnsmasq or "forward-zone" in Unbound, only it's tied to an interface as well.